# AJAX not working in my project

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am working in php codeigniter and I tried like this in my code.

```
var dataSource = $.ajax({
            url: <?php echo $url=$this->BASE_URL."home/destination_place" ?>,
            method: "POST",
            data: { id : id,firstName:firstName },
            dataType: "html"
        });
```

This is my returning array but it is not getting in the data source field

```
[{"id":"1","firstName":"dubai"},{"id":"2","firstName":"munnar"},{"id":"3","firstName":"wayanad"},{"id":"4","firstName":"kovalam"}]
```

I hope somebody will help me to solve this.
hopefully

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: `This is my returning array` - you don't show any code that deals with your "returning array" - all that code does is post and ignore the response

Comment: @JaromandaX didn't get you

Comment: you say `This is my returning array` ... what does this even mean? returning array? returning from what? there's no array in your code, so where does this returning array return from

Comment: that url return this array

Comment: urls don't return arrays by default... this function just posts to 'home/destination_place' and doesn't do anything else. the success or done function is where you can get the data...

Answer (score 1):

I tend not to use `.ajax` because it's bulky and messy. The `.get()` and `.post()` methods work well and are nice and clean.

```
var dataSource = '';
$.post('<?= $this->BASE_URL.'home/destination_place' ?>',
        { id: id, firstName: firstName },
        function(resp){ dataSource = resp; });
```

The third argument is the callback function, which takes the response as a function parameter. You can then assign it to a variable outside the callback.

Something to bear in mind is that AJAX is asynchronous. The response value will not be available until the call to the remote machine completes. For this reason, all data processing should be triggered inside the callback function, where in this case we are assigning `resp` to `dataSource`.

Comment: And this works for you? Because I tried it and it doesn't for me. Empty response if I `console.log(dataSource)`

Comment: Yes, this prototype works for me just fine. I use jQuery like this very frequently, personally and professionally. Just make sure the correct URL is ending up in the first parameter.

Comment: URL is correct,verified in network pane of dev tools, post data also verified set. still a console.log after the function returns no results despite having a clear response in the response pane. dubious... Results are json btw.

Comment: "dubious"? Here's an example you can run in your console... `$.get('google.com', function(resp){ console.log(resp); });` ... this stuff is very simple usage of jQuery. Read up on it.

Comment: it's asynchronous. when you're trying to print it, it has not yet returned.

Comment: yea thats the nature of ajax unless async is false, which isn't advised, but won't that mean that the variable won't be useful when needed as the user intends (as a variable presumably to be used with other jquery functions)?

Comment: it's just something to be aware of. the necessary processing logic should be launched by the callback function so the value is available.

Comment: yea that would be good to mention in your answer as it can be confusing

Answer (score 0):

dataType parameter is the type of data you're expecting to get from server. 
If I undearstand correctly, you want to get JSON from server, but u specified dataType as html. Try:

```
var dataSource = $.ajax({
            url: <?php echo $url=$this->BASE_URL."home/destination_place" ?>,
            method: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            data: { id : id,firstName:firstName },
        });
```

Comment: Believe the user is trying to populate the variable with the response. This won't work for that.